# I would like to define a Region of Interest in a video and only process that area

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, roi

I am having problems understanding regions of interest in opencv. I have some code that does a simple background subtraction from my `first_frame`. I am also able to draw a rectangle with my `mouse_draw_rect` function.

Now, I would like the background subtraction to only happen inside the rectangle that I draw because I would like to speed up the algorithm processing. I know I have to set some sort of Region of Interest but I tried it all yesterday and today and nothing that I have tried from tutorials have worked. Can someone help guide me through this process please?

**EDIT**: attempted to fix code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

_, first_frame = cap.read()

def mouse_draw_rect(event, x, y, flags, params):
    global point1, point2, drawing, first_frame, x1, x2, y1, y2
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        if drawing is False:
            drawing = True
            point1 = (x, y)
            x1 = (x)
            y1 = (y)
        else:
            drawing = False
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing is True:
            point2 = (x, y)
            x2 = (x)
            y2 = (y)
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MBUTTONDOWN:
        first_frame = frame

drawing = False
point1 = ()
point2 = ()
x1 = ()
x2 = ()
y1 = ()
y2 = ()

cv2.namedWindow('Original')
cv2.setMouseCallback("Original", mouse_draw_rect)

while True:

    ret, frame = cap.read( )

    if point1 and point2:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, point1, point2, (0, 0, 0),5)


    difference = cv2.absdiff(first_frame[y1:y2, x1:x2], frame[y1:y2, x1:x2])
    difference = cv2.GaussianBlur(difference, (3, 3), 0)

    _, difference = cv2.threshold(difference, 18, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)


    cv2.imshow('first frame (1)', first_frame)
    cv2.imshow('Original', frame)
    cv2.imshow('difference', difference)


    key = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if key == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is with the ROI selection event and how it is being called currently. The current implementation is not dynamic which means we are unable to visualize what ROI we are trying to select. Also, we have started processing before even selecting the ROI.

The proper way to select the ROI is that once we have captured the first frame, register the mouse click event and visualize the frame indefinitely with `imshow` and `waitKey(n)` until some specific key is pressed. Alternatively, we may be able to achieve the same effect without the infinite loop by using `waitKey(0)` (Not tested).

At this stage, we should be able to draw the desired ROI rectangle. The key factor here is the execution **must** be halted either by using an infinite loop or `waitKey(0)`. Just registering the event is not enough. After ROI selection is done, then proceed with the rest of the code.

Some recommendations are as follows:

- Avoid the usage of global variables where possible
- Create separate window for ROI selection and discard it afterwards
- Create separate functions for each individual task

Following is the complete code demonstrating correct usage of mouse click event to select the ROI for video processing:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


ORIGINAL_WINDOW_TITLE = 'Original'
FIRST_FRAME_WINDOW_TITLE = 'First Frame'
DIFFERENCE_WINDOW_TITLE = 'Difference'


canvas = None
drawing = False # true if mouse is pressed

#Retrieve first frame
def initialize_camera(cap):
    _, frame = cap.read()
    return frame


# mouse callback function
def mouse_draw_rect(event,x,y,flags, params):
    global drawing, canvas

    if drawing:
        canvas = params[0].copy()

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing = True
        params.append((x,y)) #Save first point

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing:
            cv2.rectangle(canvas, params[1],(x,y),(0,255,0),2)

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing = False
        params.append((x,y)) #Save second point
        cv2.rectangle(canvas,params[1],params[2],(0,255,0),2)


def select_roi(frame):
    global canvas
    canvas = frame.copy()
    params = [frame]
    ROI_SELECTION_WINDOW = 'Select ROI'
    cv2.namedWindow(ROI_SELECTION_WINDOW)
    cv2.setMouseCallback(ROI_SELECTION_WINDOW, mouse_draw_rect, params)
    roi_selected = False
    while True:
        cv2.imshow(ROI_SELECTION_WINDOW, canvas)
        key = cv2.waitKey(10)

        #Press Enter to break the loop
        if key == 13:
            break;


    cv2.destroyWindow(ROI_SELECTION_WINDOW)
    roi_selected = (3 == len(params))

    if roi_selected:
        p1 = params[1]
        p2 = params[2]
        if (p1[0] == p2[0]) and (p1[1] == p2[1]):
            roi_selected = False

    #Use whole frame if ROI has not been selected
    if not roi_selected:
        print('ROI Not Selected. Using Full Frame')
        p1 = (0,0)
        p2 = (frame.shape[1] - 1, frame.shape[0] -1)


    return roi_selected, p1, p2




if __name__ == '__main__':

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    #Grab first frame
    first_frame = initialize_camera(cap)

    #Select ROI for processing. Hit Enter after drawing the rectangle to finalize selection
    roi_selected, point1, point2 = select_roi(first_frame)    

    #Grab ROI of first frame
    first_frame_roi = first_frame[point1[1]:point2[1], point1[0]:point2[0], :]

    #An empty image of full size just for visualization of difference
    difference_image_canvas = np.zeros_like(first_frame)

    while cap.isOpened():

        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if ret:

            #ROI of current frame
            roi = frame[point1[1]:point2[1], point1[0]:point2[0], :]

            difference = cv2.absdiff(first_frame_roi, roi)
            difference = cv2.GaussianBlur(difference, (3, 3), 0)

            _, difference = cv2.threshold(difference, 18, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)


            #Overlay computed difference image onto the whole image for visualization
            difference_image_canvas[point1[1]:point2[1], point1[0]:point2[0], :] = difference.copy()


            cv2.imshow(FIRST_FRAME_WINDOW_TITLE, first_frame)
            cv2.imshow(ORIGINAL_WINDOW_TITLE, frame)
            cv2.imshow(DIFFERENCE_WINDOW_TITLE, difference_image_canvas)


            key = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
            if key == 27:
                break
        else:
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Pro Tip:**
Sometimes, when a camera is initialized, it takes some time to warm-up depending upon the ambient light present in the room. You may consider skipping a few initial frames to let the camera settle from the initialization phase. It can be done by defining the `initialize_camera` function in the above code as follows:

```
def initialize_camera(cap):
    for i in range(0,60): #Skip first 60 frames
        _, frame = cap.read()
    return frame
```

Comment: This was an amazing explanation, thank you. I will comb through your code and learn as much as I can from it.

Comment: @sentientnativeplant... Great. You may consider accepting the answer if it solves your problem so that this post can get off the un-answered questions' list and help the readers who encounter the same problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply crop by the area in the rectangle you have drawn.
Instead of

```
difference = cv2.absdiff(first_frame, frame)
```

use

```
difference = cv2.absdiff(first_frame[y1:y2, x1:x2], frame[y1:y2, x1:x2])
```

Comment: I am probably making a major mistake, but I attempted to apply what you suggested and it comes back with an error that y1 is not defined. I changed the code in my main text so you could see what I added.

Comment: (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) are your point1 and point2. Don't use x's and y's, use your namings

Comment: So I pull the values out like so?

difference = cv2.absdiff(first_frame[point1[1]:point2[1],point1[0]:point2[0]], frame[point1[1]:point2[1],point1[0]:point2[0]])

Comment: Unfortunately when I add it to my function it still does not apply itself to the rectangle. I will probably take a break and try and tackle it tomorrow, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

On each frame you can create a subimage using `subimage = image[y1:y2,x1:x2]` And then use the subimage for processing.

A quick and dirty implementation in you code:

Replace
`elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:`

with

`elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:`

And add the subimage:

```
    if point1 and point2:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, point1, point2, (0, 0, 0),5)
            subimg = frame[point1[1]:point2[1],point1[0]:point2[0]]
            cv2.imshow("Subimage",subimg)
```